Add an existing SQLite database to a React Native project
I am currently developing a React Native project and I need to incorporate an already populated SQLite3 database into the project. I intend to utilize SQLite FTS5, and after some research, I have decided to use the react-native-sqlite-2 package. However, I do not know of how to open an existing database within the project.
(To clarify, I do not wish to create a new database; rather, I want to add an existing populated database and open it).
